# How to make a button open a small window within the html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So you know how extensions work in Google, right? You click a button and it opens this small window within the internal webpage. I know how to make a button open an external window, but how do I make it work similarly to an extension. Basically, I'd like to have an html page where I can click a button and it'll open a small popup of another `.html` file within the first html page. So it would be this: **https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup** but where it says "A Simple Popup!" it's an .html page.

Comment: Check out [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: To add to @RobMoll comment, You can code the modal yourself (with html and CSS) or search modal library. And put iframe inside the iframe. You can also use `<dialog>` html tag, Note that if you need your modal to be exactly as in that URL you need tooltip library that allow custom html.

Comment: Your question is not clear.